# Using compareTo on a nullable Int?

Tags: android, kotlin, compareto

I am wondering the best way to check that a nullable list is greater than 0.

```
val list: List<Any>? = listOf()

if (list?.size.compareTo(1) > 0)
{
     //do something
}
```

This is causing an error when checking if greater than 0. The IDE is telling me to use another compareTo with a safe call but that leads me to the same situation. I was able to work around this by creating a value for the size, but this seems like a strange work around, and I was wondering if I am missing an easier way.

```
val count = list?.size ?: 0
if (count > 1)
{
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems in your code. The first is that you're using `compareTo()` instead of a direct comparison (e.g. `size > 0`). The other is that the use of `list?` means that any further results can be `null`, but you're not handling that.

Here's how I'd approach it:

```
val list: List<Any>? = listOf()

list?.let {
    if (it.isNotEmpty()) {

    }
}
```

Kotlin 1.3 seems to provide an `isNullOrEmpty()` method, which would let you write this instead:

```
val list: List<Any>? = listOf()

if (!list.isNullOrEmpty()) {

}
```

https://twitter.com/kotlin/status/1050426794682306562

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility with Kotlin < 1.3 you could use

```
if (list?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
    // ....
}
```

The explicit check for `true` (which is not equal to `null`) will take the branch only if the list is non-`null` (and not empty).